# Laptop freezing on shut down [Ubuntu 16.04.01]

Tags: filesystem, shutdown, freeze, inode

I have a problem with my laptop, which is freezing every time I shut it down.
The issue began a couple of weeks ago but I cannot think of any change I made nor application I installed which might have caused it.

The laptop freezes at the following screen, mentioning some errors with the filesystem and orphaned inodes:

[image: error screenshot]

After that I have to push the on/off button for a few seconds in order to switch off the laptop.

When I switch on again the laptop, I briefly see a similar screen before viewing the log-in screen.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue, please?

Comment: Does it shutdown normally if you disable your network (`sudo service networking stop`) before shutting down?

Comment: No, it doesn't; it keeps freezing on the same screen.